# Oracle - Create A View from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am new to SQL and am trying to teach myself different aspects of Oracle as a side interest. While working on a project, it asks to create a view based on the input data from other tables. How would this normally look?

I currently have four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Engineers (
    EID Integer Primary Key,
    LastName varchar(25),
    FirstName varchar(25),
    Email varchar(255),
    Graddate date
);
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
    FID Integer Primary Key,
    LastName varchar(25),
    FirstName varchar(25),
    Email varchar(255),
    Hiredate date
);
CREATE TABLE Classes (
    CID Integer Primary Key,
    Subject varchar(6),
    Catalognbr varchar(6),
    Title varchar(120)
);
CREATE TABLE ClassEnrollments (
    EnID Integer Primary Key,
    CID Integer,
    FID Integer, 
    EID Integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (CID) REFERENCES CLASSES(CID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FID) REFERENCES FACULTY(FID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EID) REFERENCES ENGINEERS(EID)
);
```

I am trying to make a view that contains the first and last name of the engineer, last name and email of the faculty member and the subject of a class for a set of inserted data into the ClassEnrollment table which looks like:

```
INSERT INTO ClassEnrollments
    (EnID, CID, FID, EID)
    Values (EnID_inc.NEXTVAL, 1, 1, 4);
```

What I have tried to do was:

```
CREATE VIEW Testers AS
SELECT e.Lastname, e.Firstname, f.Lastname, f.Email, c.Subject, c.title, en.EnID
FROM Engineers e, Faculty f, Classes c, ClassEnrollments en
WHERE e.EID = en.EID AND f.FID = en.FID AND c.CID = en.CID 
ORDER By en.ENID;
```

However, with this I get a duplicate column name error.

Comment: View is just a saved query that may be used as a table in `select` statement. Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it

Comment: It's not clear why Oracle lose some error message explanation in every new release, but an old 9i reference has very nice details for each error code. [**ORA-00957 duplicate column name**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1004903)
**Cause**: *A column name was specified twice in a CREATE or INSERT statement. Column names must be unique within a table, view, or cluster.*
**Action**: *In a CREATE statement, change one of the column names to a new, unique column name. In an INSERT statement, remove one of the duplicate names.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are not allowed to have duplicate column names in the view. You can use the [AS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E49933_01/server.770/es_eql/src/reql_statement_as.html) to rename the duplicate columns.

```
CREATE VIEW Testers AS
SELECT e.Lastname as EngLastname, EngFirstname as FacLastname, f.Lastname as fac_lastname, f.Email, c.Subject, c.title, en.EnID
FROM Engineers e, Faculty f, Classes c, ClassEnrollments en
WHERE e.EID = en.EID AND f.FID = en.FID AND c.CID = en.CID 
ORDER By en.ENID;
```

Your base query would look better if you use a JOIN clause:

```
SELECT e.Lastname as EngLastname
      ,e.Firstname as EngFirstname
      ,f.Lastname as FacLastname
      ,f.Email
      ,c.Subject
      ,c.title
      ,en.EnID    
FROM Engineers e
JOIN Faculty f
    ON Faculty.FID = ClassEnrollments.FID
JOIN Classes C
     ClassEnrollments.CID = Classes.CID 
JOIN ClassEnrollments en
    ON ClassEnrollments.EID = Engineers.EID
```